# Spring autowire by name constructor arguments

Tags: java, spring, constructor, autowired

We have a big java applications with thousands of beans, profiling the slow spring context initialization we found that the auto-wiring by type is what's taking most of the context loading time. 
Autowiring the bean by name seems to improve the context initialization by an order of magnitude.
However I couldn't find a way to auto-wire beans by name as constructor arguments.

The following is a member autowire that works fine, spring does the lookup by name:

```
class MyClass {
   @Resource
   private MyBean mybean;
}
```

But since @Resource only applies to members and methods it doesn't apply to constructor.
We tried both the @Inject with @Named and @Autowired with @Qualifier but Spring does the slow by type lookup for these approaches:

```
class MyClass {
   @Inject
   public MyClass(@Named("myBean") MyBean myBean) {
   }
}

class MyClass {

   @Autowired
   public MyClass(@Qualifer("myBean") MyBean myBean) {
   }
}
```

How to tell spring not to lookup by type when using constructor injection?

We understand the advantaged of wire by type (decouple from bean names) yet at this point context loading performance is our biggest concern.

Comment: The whole point of having annotations (meta-data) in your code is to achieve "type-safe injection". You want to give up essential feature of this injector.

Maybe the right way to approach this problem is to make your application more modular, so you don't have to build up one epicly huge ApplicationContext.

Comment: Why can't you just configure these beans in configuration?

Comment: Similar problem leads me here, do you get a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I know it is now a bit old fashioned, but wiring by name is really easy in xml, and Spring supports mixing of xml and java configuration.

Provided bean `myBean` is defined in xml of java configuration, you can write

```
<bean id="myClass" class="...MyClass">
    <constructor-arg ref = "myBean"/>
</bean>
```

or in case of multiple arguments :

```
<bean id="myClass" class="...MyClass">
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref = "myBean"/>
    <constructor-arg index="1" ref = "myOtherBean"/>
</bean>
```

EDIT

Alternatively in a java config way you can have :

```
@Configuration
public class MyClassConfig() {

@Autowire
@Qualifier("myBean")
MyBean myBean;

@Bean
MyClass myclass = new MyClass(myBean);
}
```

Thanks to jny for suggesting it.

Comment: right, thanks, I know I can do that, I wonder if there's a way I can continue with the component-scan and wiring approach, if I can tell spring to use the by name wiring.